# Accessing array class member within class function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, this

I have 2 classes Y, X. I want to create a member of class X being an array of instances of class Y.

```
class Y 
{
public:
    Y();
    ~Y();  
    void func();
    int n;
};
```

I read somewhere I should use a pointer (perhaps pointer to begginning of array of pointers?) in order to be able to interact with this data.

```
class X 
{
public:
    X();
    ~X();      
    void setY(int n);
    Y *yy; 
};
```

So I tried to create a function setY in class X to handle adding subsequent elements of array yy. I am struggling with
1) creating an array of instances of class Y correctly 
2) in function setY - accessing elements of the array yy and interacting with them - calling function func() (I am thinking of this-> pointer here).

I am still a begginner, so my problem might seem obvious.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Y>` member in `X`, not a pointer.

Comment: just a vector, not a pointer to vector? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) creating an array of instances of class Y correctly

One way to create an array of instances of class Y is:

```
const int N = 10;

X::X()
{
    yy = new Y[N]; // create array of 10 instances of class Y.
}
```

> 2) in function setY - accessing elements of the array yy and interacting with them - calling function func() (I am thinking of this-> pointer here).

```
void X::setY(int n)
{
    assert(n < N); // check that n is less than N (10)
    yy[n].func(); // access n-th element.
}
```

However, there are better ways, for example, using [std::vector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivof_V3bbTAhUaS2MKHd2vD4wQFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fvector%2Fvector%2F&usg=AFQjCNEIvTQYMmtXXDUrrqe-Oc1wxLJJog):

```
#include <vector>

class X
{
public:
    X();
    ~X();
    void setY(int n);
    std::vector<Y> yy; 
};

X::X() : yy(N) // create std::vector of 10 instances of class Y.
{
}

void X::setY(int n)
{
    yy[n].func(); // access n-th element.
}
```

If your `class X` will only contain fixed number of instances of Y you can simplify it as this:

```
class X
{
public:
    X();
    ~X();
    void setY(int n);
    Y[10] yy; 
};

X::X()
{
}

void X::setY(int n)
{
    yy[n].func(); // access n-th element.
}
```

Comment: Trying to acess yy, do I not need to use this->yy[n].func(); ?

Comment: @chocc you could, but in c++ `this` inside member functions isn't required.

Comment: Thank you, just last question: if I create yy = new Y[N]; like this, is my defined constructor being called (one with no parameters taken) or another - default(?) - constructor, which doesn't change any class members like my one does?

Comment: @chocc it will call your `Y::Y()` constructor which effectively becomes default constructor of Y.